# Piping of stream from wget to tar

Tags: tar, wget

I want to download the Linux kernel and unarchive it in one step. There are a lot [manuals](https://www.tecmint.com/download-and-extract-tar-files-with-one-command/) about it. So I tried:

```
$ wget  https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz | tar -xav -C /home/a/myKernel/
--2023-05-06 03:04:38--  https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz
Resolving cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)... 146.75.49.176, 2a04:4e42:7c::432
Connecting to cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)|146.75.49.176|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 136934448 (131M) [application/x-xz]
Saving to: ‘linux-6.3.1.tar.xz’

linux-6.3.1.tar.xz                                          100%[========================================================================================================================================>] 130.59M  9.08MB/s    in 14s     

2023-05-06 03:04:52 (9.32 MB/s) - ‘linux-6.3.1.tar.xz’ saved [136934448/136934448]

tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I also tried:

```
$ aria2c https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz | tar -xz -C /home/a/myKernel/

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Every time, I get errors. But these two commands work OK:

```
$ wget  https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz
$ tar xavf linux-6.3.1.tar.xz
```

How can I download and unarchive the Linux kernel in a single command?

Comment: **(A) ISSUE** : When you have the Pipe , the `wget` is still making the file "linux-6.3.1.tar.xz" with almost no output in STDOUT which is given to `tar` ( meaning : `tar` is not getting the file , `tar` is getting almost nothing ! ) which naturally is not looking like a tar file. **(B) Confirmation** : When you try the last 2 Commands , it works because the `wget` is Implicitly making the file "linux-6.3.1.tar.xz" which you are then giving to `tar`. **(C) Double Confirmation** : We see the Pipe Command failing with output like ".... Saving to .... Saved ...." showing that STDOUT has nothing.

Comment: **(D) Solution** : Explicitly tell `wget` to not write to "linux-6.3.1.tar.xz" , rather write it to STDOUT , which `tar` can access.

Comment: **(E) What to Change** : In the Pipe `wget` , you have to use `--output-document=-` [[ Equivalently : `-O -` ]] to achieve that Solution !

Answer (score 11):

With GNU `tar`, `tar xf file.tar.xz` invokes `xz -d` to uncompress the file on the file, but for some reason,  that doesn't work for `-`.

Switching to libarchive's `bsdtar` would work:

```
wget -qO- https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz |
  bsdtar xvf -
```

But you could also invoke `xz -d` by yourself:

```
wget -qO - https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz |
  xz -d |
  tar xvf -
```

Which would work with any `tar` implementation.

The GNU `tar` manual has:

> The only case when you have to specify a decompression option while
> reading the archive is when reading from a pipe or from a tape drive
> that does not support random access.  However, in this case GNU 'tar'
> will indicate which option you should use.  For example:
>
> ```
> $ cat archive.tar.gz | tar tf -
> tar: Archive is compressed.  Use -z option
> ```

Here:

```
$ cat file.tar.xz | tar tf -
tar: Archive is compressed. Use -J option
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So, if using GNU `tar`, you can explicitly use `-J` or `--xz` for `tar` to invoke `xz -d` to uncompress the input stream on the fly.

```
wget -qO- https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz |
  gnu-tar Jxvf -
```

In any case, you forgot the `-O -` without which `wget` would store the downloaded file into a local file instead of printing it to stdout (here the pipe to `tar`), maybe you were confusing `wget` with `curl` which outputs the download to stdout by default. `-q` (quiet) is like `curl`'s `-s` (silent) and suppresses the progress information that you otherwise get by default.

Comment: Did you notice that OP did not use `-O-` when using `Pipe wget` ? **I may be wrong** , but this might not be the Correct Answer. I have Explained the Issue ( & the Solution ) in my Comments to the OP Question Post. I request you to check that.

Comment: @Prem, you're right, I should have added a note about that. Done now.

Comment: Yes , that is the Core Point which will resolve the Issue. I am not sure whether OP will encounter the `tar` issue you have highlighted. That will be known after that "Original Issue" is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
wget -q -O - https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.3.1.tar.xz |
    tar xJvf -
```

- `-O` define the output file, here, `STDOUT`: `-`
- `-q` is quiet mode

Then:

```
cd linux-6.3.1/
ls -1
```

```
arch/
block/
certs/
[...]
```